# Which of the following is (are) correct?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, finite-fields, group-homomorphism

Let $F$ be a finite field.If $f:F\rightarrow F$,given by $f(x)=x^3$ is a ring homomorphism,then

$(A)$$F=\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$.

$(B)$$F=\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ or $Characteristic$ of $F=3$.

$(C)$$F=\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ or $\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$.

$(D)$$Characteristic$ of $F$ is $3$.

Solution:

If  $F=\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z=${$0,1,2$} or $F=\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z=${$0,1$},then elements of $F$  are  satisfying the operation preserving properties.This leads me **(PLEASE CHECK!!)** to the  selection of options$(A)$,$(B)$ and $(C)$.

I'm not getting how to accept or discard option $(D)$.

Please give some suggestions  about my attempt......

Comment: How did you get that the order of $f(2)$ was $2$? Anyway, are you familiar with what is known as freshman's dream?

Comment: Also, it is not quite clear how to read the options. I mean, are you answering whether you can conclude that what is written must hold, or are you answering that in the case written, the map is a homomorphism?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft:apology,i miscalculated  the order..

Comment: You should probably bring back those parts of your attempt that were not faulty, as otherwise people are likely to close the question for lack of context.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft:Got it!!

Comment: The way I read this problem the answer is (B). It is true that the map in question is a homomorphism *if* $F$ is $\mathbb{Z}/2$, but it could also be $\mathbb{Z}/3$, so (A) is false. Similarly, $F$ could be $\mathbb{Z}/2$ or $\mathbb{Z}/3$, but $F$ could also be an extension field of $\mathbb{Z}/3$, making (C) false.

Comment: @DavidHill I agree. I had misread the statement in (B) in a way that made none of them true, which confused me.

Comment: @DavidHill:Why we're looking for the extension of $\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: @DavidHill:In your last comment,you talked about the extension field of $\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$.My question is why are we considering the extension field of $\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$?

Comment: @DavidHill:This is the argument for the validity of option $(B)$:using additive properties of ring homomorphism,$f(x+y)=(x+y)^3=x^3+y^3+3x^2y+3xy^2$.It will be a ring homomorphism when $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$.Which is possible if either $F=\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ or $Characteristic$ of $F$ is 3.

Comment: @DavidHill:Please elaborate your views regarding option $C$.

Comment: What David is getting at is that .... (not spoiling) ... have you checked what happens with $F=\Bbb{Z}[i]/3\Bbb{Z}[i]$? Bear in mind that "none of the above" may be an option! You need to **justify** the conclusion. What if $F=\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}$ for some other prime $p$?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen:If $F=\mathbb Z[i]/3\mathbb Z[i]$,then still $f$ is a homomorphism as if $z_1,z_2\in \mathbb Z[i]/3\mathbb Z[i]$,then $f(z_1+z_2)=(z_1+z_2)^3=z_1^3+z_2^3+3z_1^2z_2+3z_1z_2^2=z_1^3+z_2^3=f(z_1)+f(z_2)$.Is this all we've to check for $F=\mathbb Z[i]/3\mathbb Z[i]$?

Comment: More or less. What does that say about the truth of the alternatives?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen:If $F=\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$,then  if $x,y\in \mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$,then $f(x+y)=(x+y)^3=x^3+y^3+3x^2y+3xy^2$.This is all upto which i'm reaching,please help me in reaching some conclusion..

Comment: With that example you can say that (C) is false, right?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen:You meant to say that there is another possibility for $F$ to be $\mathbb Z[i]/3\mathbb Z[i]$?If i'm getting you correctly then $\mathbb Z[i]/3\mathbb Z[i]$ extends the alternatives in option $C$,thus making it false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are to make the following observations (you justify the unclear conclusions):

1. If $f$ is a homomorphism of fields, then
   $$2=1+1=f(1)+f(1)=f(1+1)=f(2)=2^3.$$ This implies that $F$ has characteristic either two or three.
2. $f$ is the identity mapping of $\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$.
3. If $F$ has characteristic three, then for all $z_1,z_2\in F$ we have
   $$F(z_1+z_2)=(z_1+z_2)^3=z_1^3+3z_1^2z_2+3z_1z_2^2+z_2^3=z_1^3+z_2^3.$$ This implies that $f$ is a homomorphism of rings.
4. If $F$ has characteristic two, and there exists an element $z\in F$, $z\neq0,1$, then we can conclude that $z+z^2\neq0.$
5. If $F$ and $z$ are as in step 4, then
   $$f(1+z)=(1+z)^3=1+3z+3z^2+z^3=1+z+z^2+z^3=f(1)+f(z)+(z+z^2),$$
   so $f$ is not a homomorphism of rings.
6. Putting all this together we see that (B) is correct and the rest of the claims are false. For full credit it is important that you understand the logic of this conclusion. I gathered that this may be a difficult step.

Comment: The OP showed some work in the comments. Therefore I decide to post this that is somewhere between an extended hint and a full solution depending on your vantage point.

Comment: :Please check the proof of $(4)$:Since every field,$F$ is an integral domain.According to the assumption $Ch(F)=2$.So,for $z\in F$ we have,$2z=0\implies z+z=0\implies z=-z$.Now considering the idempotents of $F$,$z^2=z\implies z=0,1$.But $z\neq 0,1$.So,$z^2 \neq z\implies z^2-z\neq 0\implies z^2+z\neq 0$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen:How  you've  decided whether characteristic of $F$ is either 2 or 3?

Comment: @Picaso We deduced that $2=2^3$. What does that tell you?

Comment: @PKStyles That's ok, I think. At least if you know what idempotents a field can have. I had in mind: $$z^2+z=0\implies z(z+1)=0\implies z=0\ \text{ or}\ z+1=0.$$

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen:Which of the fields,$\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ or  $\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$ you're looking?I'm got confused because if we look at  $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$,then it has characteristic 2,while if we take $\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$ into consideration then it has characteristic 3.I'm not getting your approach of reaching to the conclusion via $2=2^3$ about the characteristic of $F$ to be $2$ or $3$.Please elaborate this point.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen:Why option $(C)$ is not correct as $\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$ also satisfies  conditions of being the domain of the field homomorphism?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen:Why option $(A)$ is false as $f$ is the identity mapping of $\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z=${$0,1,2$} as $f(0)=0^3=0$,$f(1)=1^3=1$,$f(2)=2^3=8=2$?

Comment: @Picaso That argument (your last comment) shows that the clause "if $F=\Bbb{Z}/3\Bbb{Z}$, then $f$ is a homomorphism" is correct. The question is about the correctness of the clause "if $f$ is a homomorphism, then ..."

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen:I'm a beginner.Sorry,i'm not getting your argument correctly.What is the difference between these two clauses?What i'm getting from the first clause is,*First choose the field and then decide whether the given map is homomorphism*,while the second clause tells us to *start with the map(homomorphism) and then tell what the field is.But,the resulting field in the second clause will automatically(here atleast) results in the field in the first clause(in specific)*.Right?

Comment: @Picaso: If $f$ is a homomorphism, it doesn't follow that $F=\Bbb{Z}/3\Bbb{Z}$. $F$ could also be, for example $\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$. Therefore A is false. If $f$ is a homomorphism, it doesn't follow that characteristic of $F$ is three, for $F$ could also be $\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$. Therefore D is false. Similarly $F$ could be any field of characteristic three, so C is false. Finally $F$ must have characteristic two or three, and if $F$ has characteristic two, it must be $\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$ for $f$ to be a homomorphism. Therefore B is true.

Comment: In other words, we are given that $f$ is a homomorphism, and then the question asks whether it follows that we can conclude certain facts about $F$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen:What about the characteristic  notion?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen:thanks a lot.You guided me excellently.

Comment: @Picaso:Thank you,for showing interest in my problem!!